# Is public synchronized void run() a bad idea?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class that extends Thread that downloads files. I want to ensure that only one download is occurring at once, so I have a static reference to the class, and check to see if it is null before creating a new reference. However occasionally I notice that another instance of this class is created, and therefore downloading on a different thread. I'm trying to figure out what could cause this, however, would it be a bad idea in general to mark the run() method of the Thread to synchronized (or the method that calls start()) ? Are there any side effects to be aware of?

Comment: You should never call the `run()` method of a `Thread` object from anything other than one thread, the thread that `start()`'ed it.

Comment: I'm never calling run directly, I'm calling  this.start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ensure only a single instance of your said object get created in lifetime of JVM. for that there is a much famous singleton pattern which ensure this.

Make the constructor private. Give a static factory method to create the instance.

Example:

```
Downloader{

  private static volatile Downloader iDownloader=null; 
  private Downloader(){
  }

 public static Downloader createDownloader(){
     if(iDownloader==null){
     synchronized(Downloader.class){
      if(iDownloader==null)
       iDownloader=new Downloader();
       }
      }
  return iDownloader; 
}
```

}

Comment: This is not completely thread-safe, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: Should not the `iDownloader` be `static`?

Comment: Also, make `iDownloader` `volatile`.

Comment: Or simply initialize the Downloader in its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

if you want limit number of downloads running at any time you should use a semaphore mechanism in this way u can scale number of downloads, you should not need any synchronized run in this way, also in future if u need two downloads run you just increase your semaphore size

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to synchronize access to the static flag.  And it's fine to do that with  `synchronized` methods.  However when you're all done you will have implemented a lock.  So have a look at the Java [Lock class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).  The method that starts the file transfer needs to grab the lock before starting the download thread.  The thread releases it after either the download is complete or has failed.  As the docs point out, release must occur with 100% certainty, or all downloads will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your thread a pipeline thread by using Looper class from Android Framework and enqueue  your download requests by a Handler  instance

here is a nice tutorial that might help you
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/